# Casting varchar to date in where query Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sorting, date, laravel-5

I am trying to pick a collection of data from a range using the date as the sorting column. But the problem is that the date in my table is saved as a varchar string.

NOTE: The varchar field type needs to stay as it used by some non laravel, legacy codebase, and I will disrupt service if altered to date type.

I have tried casting it but it doesn't work.

This is the code in the controller

```
        switch ($range) {
        case 'thisWeek':
            $start = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('d-m-y');
            $end = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->format('d-m-Y');     
            break;

        case 'thisMonth':
            $start = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y');
            $end = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y');
            // dd($start, $end);
            break;


        case 'last90Days':
            $start = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
            $end = Carbon::now()->subDays(90)->format('d-m-Y');

            // dd($start, $end);
            break;

        case 'last30Days':
            $start = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
            $end = Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->format('d-m-Y');
            break;


        case 'year':
            $start = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
            $end = Carbon::now()->year;
            $end = "31-12-". $end;
            break;

        // case 'all':
        //  $route = $name .".". "index";
        //  return redirect()->Route($route);

        default:
            session()->flash("alert-danger", "no range selected");
            return redirect()->back();
            break;
    }

    if($name=="activitylog"){

        // return $start . ' <br>' . $end;

        $logs = Payment::where("payDate", '<', $start)->where("payDate", ">", $end)->
                        orderBy("payDate", "DESC")->
                        paginate(20);
    }
    else{
        $logs = Payment::where("description", $description[$name])->
                    where("payDate", '=<', $start)->where("payDate", ">=", $end)->
                    orderBy("payDate", "DESC")->
                    paginate(20);
```

the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Payment extends Model
{
    protected $table = "payments";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $cast = ["payDate"=> "DATE"];
}
```

When the user makes a request for any of the ranges I wish to compare and give an answer.

[image: dates example]

the image for the database config is above
and the structure below
[image: table structure]

Comment: in your schema where you created it, try to use the `$table->date('payDate');` to create the date field instead of varchar, and in your model use `public $dates = ['payDate']` as a property. Then you should be able to just insert the carbon instance and laravel will do the rest.

Comment: Sidenote: laravel 5.2 hasn't received updates for almost a year now. Consider upgrading. https://endoflife.software/programming-languages/frameworks/laravel

Comment: @Tschallacka I can't really edit the database as it is a legacy project and has so many other aspects of the code I don't wan to touch that depends on it. The other aspects are not built with Laravel. So I just want to be able to find a workaround with laravel

Comment: @Loek I honestly wish I could but I can't.

Comment: @Thirdwrist Please include that information in your question since it's quite relevant to a possible answer that the varchar field type needs to stay.

Comment: @Thirdwrist fair enough, just pointing it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function of mysql.

The raw SQL query you're looking for is:

See it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a40090/8

```
select * from `test` where str_to_date(`payDate`, '%d-%m-%Y') > str_to_date('31-12-2007', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

With [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) you tell MySQL in what format the date is formatted which helps MySQL to give back the proper date for sorting and such.

Your Eloquent query will then come to look somewhat like this:

```
 /** put it like this so we don't have to repeat it everywhere where needed **/
 $paydate_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(`payDate`, '%d-%m-%Y')");

 /** encoding the raw query. the ? is populated by setBindings() **/
 $start_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d-%m-%Y')");
 $end_raw = DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d-%m-%Y')");


  $query = Payment::where($paydate_raw, '<', $start_raw)->where($paydate_raw, ">", $end_raw)->
                    orderBy('paydate', "DESC")->
                    setBindings([$start, $end])->
                    paginate(20);
  // debugging output.
  //echo $query->toSql();
```

Note the above code is just a concept, I haven't tested it out, but it should work. Take a look also at the SQL fiddle to see how it should respond in raw.

Comment: This is awesome! thanks. Let me try it out. On a second thought do I need to prevent SQL Injection in my query? since It does not have any user defined parameter. All the dates are defined by me when the user chooses an option in the switch statement.

Comment: Rule of thumb, always use prepared statements. You will never know what's going to happen in two years with this code.